# CSS3 Animation working but no sucess with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css

Hi i am trying to fade the overlay over the image. I have successfully done it using CSS3. But its not fading slowly, so i thought of using `.animate` function of jQuery. But its not working at all

**[CSS3 Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/aCu36/light/)**

And here is

**[jQuery Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/aCu36/2/)**

Comment: For me it seems that jquery implementation works. What you mean by "not working at all".

Comment: @krasimir as you can see in CSS3 demo overlay is showing up when hover over, but in jquery case its not showing up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hi, I have fixed the issue.

```
$(document).ready(function () { 
    $("ul.search-item-list li").mouseover(function () {
        $(this).find(".sil-img-overlay").fadeIn();
    });

    $("ul.search-item-list li").mouseleave(function () {
        $(this).find(".sil-img-overlay").fadeOut('fast');
    });
});
```

Please refer below link.

http://jsfiddle.net/aCu36/3/

Comment: LInk is not working Bozzzz :)

Answer (score 1):

You can't animate the *display* property. You should use *opacity* for the purpose.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var speed = 500;
    $("ul.search-item-list li").on("mouseover", function () {
        $(this).find(".sil-img-overlay").stop().animate({
            opacity: 1
        }, speed);
    }).on("mouseout", function() {
        $(this).find(".sil-img-overlay").stop().animate({
            opacity: 0
        }, speed);
    });
});
```

demo -> http://jsfiddle.net/aCu36/11/

Also if you use jquery you don't need to set up the transition property.

Comment: oh.. didnt knew display property cant be animated. Thanks for the info and the answer brother. :)